# Get sender's tag of a programmatically set button ios

Tags: ios

I wish to get the sender's tag of a programmatically set button.
i have set many buttons with tags programmatically and when the app is running and one of the buttons is tapped i wish to get the sender's tag back.

Answer (score 0):

An example in my project. This `@IBAction` is connected with `7` buttons, from `Monday` to `Sunday`.

```
@IBAction func OnBtnWeekDay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let day = sender.tag - 1
    //....
}
```

Main point is the parameter of function:  `(_ sender: UIBUtton)`

Comment: the buttons arent on storyboard

Comment: share your code of making a button programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Make a button programmatically e.g in **viewdidload** and set it's tag and add action to it using the following code

```
//make a button programmatically e.g in viewdidload
 let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
 button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
 button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

//set tag to any integer value
 button.tag = 1
//add to view controllers view or where ever you want
 self.view.addSubview(button)

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

  print("Button tapped")
  print("Buttons Tag is \(sender.tag)")  

}
```

**Tested and verified** this solution my self. see the screen shot

[image: Button tag]